# Android launch activity remove parent using a notification

Tags: android, android-intent, android-notifications

I'm trying to get a dialog themed activity to clear the parent view when opened from a notification.

```
public class addNotification extends BroadcastReceiver {
NotificationManager nm;
final int x = -100;
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent openAdd = new Intent(context,AddDialog.class).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent createShortcut = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, x, openAdd, 0);
        nm = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Notification.Builder buildNotification = new Notification.Builder(context)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.add_task)
                .setContentTitle("Quick Entry")
                .setContentText("Click here enter data")
                .setTicker("quick entry service started.")
                .setAutoCancel(false)
                .setContentIntent(createShortcut);
    Notification notification = buildNotification.build();
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
        buildNotification.setDefaults(Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT);
        nm.notify(x, notification);
    }
}
```

Now when the activity is in the recents menu, clicking the notification will jump to the app where the activity is contained. If the app is removed from recents, the app will perform the wanted function, which is to produce an overlay over any app that is currently being used for quick data entry.

How can I clear the stack of the application, so that only the activity with the intent is shown, and not any parent activities?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using the `singleInstance` [launch mode](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode).

> Same as "singleTask", except that the system doesn't launch any other
>   activities into the task holding the instance. The activity is always
>   the single and only member of its task.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, your solution worked as needed :)

However I was wondering if it is possible to prevent this from overriding the stack on the recents menu. If I added data using the quick entry method, when I click back on the app in the recents menu, it shouldn't re-open the the quick entry method, but the parent activity.